# How to associate Rails models before one has saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to build a blogging app and I'm using trix text editor and CarrierWave.

Trip editor allows you to drag images into the text area and I've managed to get image uploads working by posting images to their own BlogImages controller and model using the following code:

```
#blog_images_controller.rb:

def create
  @image = BlogImage.create(image_params)
  @image.image = params[:image]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @image.save
      format.json { render :json => { url: @image.image.url } }
    end
  end
end

private
def image_params
  params.require(:image).permit(:image)
end

#blog_images.coffee:

(->
  host = undefined
  uploadAttachment = undefined
  document.addEventListener 'trix-attachment-add', (event) ->
    attachment = undefined
    attachment = event.attachment
    if attachment.file
      return uploadAttachment(attachment)
    return
  host = '/blog_images'

  uploadAttachment = (attachment) ->
    file = undefined
    form = undefined
    xhr = undefined
    file = attachment.file
    form = new FormData
    form.append 'Content-Type', file.type
    form.append 'image[image]', file
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
    xhr.open 'POST', host, true

    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) ->
      progress = undefined
      progress = event.loaded / event.total * 100
      attachment.setUploadProgress progress

    xhr.onload = ->
      href = undefined
      url = undefined
      url = href = JSON.parse(@responseText).url
      attachment.setAttributes
        url: url
        href: href

    xhr.send form

  return
).call this
```

My problem now is that I have a saved BlogImage but the blog which they need to be associated to hasn't yet been created, so I can't set this association up. I'm quite new to Rails so any guidance would be great.

Comment: You should take a look at nested forms: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

 You should not be creating associated models before main one is saved. What happens if someone uploads dozen of images and than chooses not to submit the blog form? You will be left with junk image models.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to save the Blog at the same time as its BlogImages using nested attributes.  You'll need to make sure associations between the two models are setup correctly in each model (Blog and BlogImage).

in your `Blog` model:

`has_many :blog_images`

in your `BlogImage` model:

`belongs_to :blog`

Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :blog_images` in the Blog model

Change your BlogController's strong parameters to accept the nested attributes, something like this:

```
def params
  params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :body, :published_on, blog_images_attributes: [:image_url, :another_image_attribute])
end
```

Then when you save your Blog record, all BlogImages nested within will be associated and saved as well.

There are a number of parts to this process, so I'd check out a tutorial like this: http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/ruby-ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes